# k-fold CV Bias-Variance Trade-Off

Tags: cross-validation

I am confused from a seemingly contradict explanation in the book ISL.

In page 183 (5.1.4 Bias-Variance Trade-Off for k-Fold Cross-Validation),
I found the sentence: advantage of k-fold CV is that it often gives more accurate estimates of the test error rate than does LOOCV (Leave-One-Out CV).
And this sentence: Therefore, from the perspective of bias reduction, it is clear that LOOCV is to be preferred to k-fold CV.

I totally understood what is the meaning of the second sentence. But, in my view point, the first one is saying opposite thing. How can I understand the first sentence?

Thank you for your time to read this question.

Comment: While I can guess what book you are talking about, please give a full reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bais-variance problem.

If you do LOOCV, you will end up with a high variance, but a low biais, given you go through every single point one by one. Each score will be highly different increase the variance but the bais will be almost non existant because you train with almost everything.

In a k-fold you will reduce the variance because you will average the performance over a larger sample but the biais will increase because of the sub selection of the k folds.

I guess that in this book "accurate" has to be understood as low variance, meaning closer to the real, underlying, value. Something is accurate if it is well determined and close its true value, meaning it has a low variance around its true value.